# Can't get ScrollTo jquery plugin working?

Tags: jquery, css, scrollto

Thinking it has something to do with my container div and their CSS.  But I am trying to get the months to scroll horizontally.  It just isn't working.  Any ideas?

The divs SHOULD be floating left of each other - not scrolling horizontally but vertically.  Also, you need to make sure the Preview quadrant is big enough to view correctly.

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

// active class swapping on menu       
jQuery("#nm12-menu li").click(function (a) {

    // style stuff
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");    
    jQuery(this).siblings( "#nm12-menu li").removeClass("active");

    // now scroll!
    var myHash = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
    jQuery('.scrollme').stop().scrollTo(myHash,800); 
    a.preventDefault();  
    });

});​
```

Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/velcrobots/ffAsR/10/

Comment: anywhere else you could host this live? its hard to debug things of this particular nature on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floated children are contained directly in the scroll container, so they're wrapping underneath each other because the container is the same width as they are.

You have a couple of options:

1. Place an inner div between the scrolling div and the children, which has a `width` set to the total width of the children.
2. Change the `float`s to `display: inline-block` and set `white-space: nowrap` on the scroll div.